# Notation alternative for $\max\left[\sum_{j=1}^pg(a_j)\right]-\min\left[\sum_{j=1}^pg(a_j)\right]$ for a linear function $g:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}$

Tags: notation

I would like to find an alternative notation for$$\max \left [\sum \limits _{j=1}^p\operatorname{g}(a_j)\right ]-\min \left [\sum \limits _{j=1}^p\operatorname{g}(a_j)\right ]$$where $g(\cdot )$ is a linear function $\mathbb{R}^n\to \mathbb{R}$ and $a_j$ is a vector. I find it quite inelegant. Do you think this can be simplified?

Thank you.

Comment: Do you have additional structure? Is $g$ linear?

Comment: @Plussoyeur Yes, sorry. It is a modified moment function for the univariate case.

Comment: Is $p$ fixed? The min and max are over the $a_i$'s?

Comment: $p$ is fixed. Yes.

Comment: Well then because $g$ is linear, why do you need to optimise over $p$ vectors and not just one? Just call $A = \sum_{j=1}^p a_j$ and optimise over $A$?

Comment: $a_j$ are independent

Comment: If $g$ linear, $\sum_{j=1}^p g(a_j) = g(\sum_{j=1}^p a_j)$ then the optimisation problem of finding $p$ vectors to optimise $g$ evaluated at the sum of the vectors is equivalent to the problem of finding a unique vector optimising $g$. No? Independent or not.

Comment: Sure, you're right

Comment: Do you thing could be possible to avoid $max(), min()$?

Comment: No. That's the core of the problem so you cannot avoid that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because $g$ is linear:
$$
\max_{A \in \mathbb{R}^n} g(A) - \min_{A \in \mathbb{R}^n} g(A) 
$$